# What is the difference in meaning between "spill coffee on the floor", "spill coffee over the floor" and "spill coffee all over the floor"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

What is the difference in meaning between *spill coffee on the floor*, *spill coffee over the floor* and *spill coffee all over the floor?*

> Yesterday I spilled coffee **on** the floor.
>
> Yesterday I spilled coffee **over** the floor.
>
> Yesterday I spilled coffee **all over** the floor.

Comment: They're all perfectly idiomatic, and mean the same thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Perhaps, although "all over" seems to suggest that a fairly wide area of the floor was affected, while in the case of "on", it might all be in one small area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FumbleFingers says they all mean the same thing really, but they imply different amounts. *All over* usually means *everywhere*, so that has more of a sense of covering the floor - probably not literally in this case, but definitely making a mess!

*On* doesn't really imply any particular amount. It could be a little, it could be a lot, you just know that coffee was spilled.

Personally I don't hear *over* used in this way very much (on its own, as opposed to *all over*), but it has the same sense of being spread out a bit, instead of being in one place - just not as much as *all over*. *Over* can also mean "over the edge of something", which doesn't apply to the floor, but it might for "over the table" or "over the balcony".

Comment: "Personally I don't hear over used in this way" - agreed.  We don't typically "spill coffee over" things.  Occasionally, we "pour coffee over" something: *to make an affogato, put a little scoop of ice cream in a cup, then pour a shot of espresso over the ice cream*